# How to Click/ Press Bar Button on Navigation Item programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have iPhone as below.

[image]

What I want is click `Refresh` button on clicking the `Delete` button ** programmatically**.

**Note:** I have provided tag also to `Refresh` button.

Comment: Why dont you init the rightbarbutton item with a uibutton and perform a selector on its click? you can call its method any time you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume u have `delete and refresh actions` say

```
 -(IBAction)deleteAction:(id)sender 
 -(IBAction)refreshAction:(id)sender:
```

Now on `delete action` `call` `refresh action` simply like this:

```
-(IBAction)deleteAction:(id)sender
{
    [self refreshAction:btnRefresh]; //provide refresh action along with refersh button
    //I mean here act according to refresh method.
}
```

Comment: I believe same button can't have Action and property **both**.. so I can't give name to refresh button as `btnRefresh`.

Comment: i m not getting  what wrote in comment.

Comment: what is `btnRefresh`. Is it property connected to Refresh Button?